# How to integrate Google Sheet to Chrome Extension

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-sheets

I retrieved the token successfully. Here are the steps that I tried using OAuth.

1. Create your manifest.json

   ```
    {
        "name": "Sample Extension",
        "version": "1.0",
        "description": "Hello World",
        "permissions": ["identity", "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/"],
        "author": "Jess",
        "background": {
          "scripts": ["background.js"],
          "persistent": true
        },
        "content_scripts": [{
          "matches": ["file:///*"],
          "js"     : ["popup.js"]
        }],
        "browser_action": {
          "default_popup": "popup.html",
          "default_icon": "images/get_started16.png",
          "default_title": "This is a sample extension"
        },
       "oauth2": {
          "client_id": "client_ID",
          "scopes": [
              "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets"
         ]},
        "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval' https://apis.google.com/; object-src 'self'",
        "manifest_version": 2
      }
   ```
2. The `Client_ID` is available in `https://console.developers.google.com`.

[image]

3. You will need to create the OAuth client ID credential and select Chrome App as the application type. Make sure that the application ID is similar to the ID of the extension. Then copy the generated `clientID`. I have enabled the Sheets API from the console.

[image]

[image]

Generated `clientID`.

[image]

4. Here's the `background.js`:

   ```
      chrome.identity.getAuthToken({ 'interactive': true }, getToken);

      function getToken(token) {
        console.log('this is the token: ', token);
      }
   ```

I will add the other files here:

pop.js

```
function popup(e) {
    var henlo = "I\'m here for you :)";
    alert("Him : " +henlo );
}
  var plusBtn = document.querySelector('#clickMe');
  plusBtn.addEventListener('click', popup);
```

pop.html

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
    <head>
      <style>
        body {
          width: 100px;
          height: 100px
        }
        button {
          background-color:#577FC6;
          color: #ffffff;
          margin:0 auto;
          border: 1px solid #000000;
          display:block;
          width:80px;
        }
      </style>
    </head>
    <body>
      <span>Try and click the button for surprise :) </span>
      <button id="clickMe">Click Me!</button>
      <script src="popup.js"></script>
    </body>
  </html>
```

This is the log for the token, it is successfully retrieved.

[image]

My issue, for now, is how to use the GAPI client to access the spreadsheets. I have also tried the approach from this [github post](https://gist.github.com/omarstreak/7908035c91927abfef59) and eventually I encountered this error:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://apis.google.com/js/client.js'
>   from origin 'chrome-extension://fajgeimckmkdokmdbpkglamjpfcekcpp' has
>   been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header
>   is present on the requested resource.

Could anyone have a workaround for this?

Comment: I also tried this approach from this [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/xhr) and it will need my extension to be published/whitelisted for security purposes for accessing Google accounts. I'm still on the test phase of my app so I'm not planning to register my extension in CWS yet.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I solved my problem!!!

I overlooked this part of the documentation [OAuth2: Authenticate Users with Google](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/tut_oauth). I'm so stupid hahaha!

Alright, this is how I integrate Google Sheets to my Extension. I used this method for initial:

```
 GET https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/{spreadsheetId}/values/{range}
```

This is my updated `manifest.json`:

```
 {
     "name": "Sample Extension",
     "version": "1.0",
     "description": "Hello World",
     "permissions": ["identity", "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/"],
     "author": "Jess",
     "background": {
       "scripts": ["background.js"],
       "persistent": true
     },
     "content_scripts": [{
       "matches": ["file:///*"],
       "js"     : ["popup.js"]
     }],
     "browser_action": {
       "default_popup": "popup.html",
       "default_icon": "images/get_started16.png",
       "default_title": "This is a sample extension"
     },
    "oauth2": {
       "client_id": "client_ID",
       "scopes": [
           "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets",          
           "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive",
           "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly",
           "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file",
           "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets.readonly"
      ]},
     "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval' https://apis.google.com/; object-src 'self'",
     "manifest_version": 2
   }
```

This is my updated `background.js`:

```
   chrome.identity.getAuthToken({ 'interactive': true }, getToken);

   function getToken(token) {
     console.log('this is the token: ', token);
  let init = {
    method: 'GET',
    async: true,
    headers: {
      Authorization: 'Bearer ' + token,
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    'contentType': 'json'
  };
  fetch(
      https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/{spreadsheetId}/values/{range},
      init)
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then(function(data) {
        console.log(data)
      });
   }
```

I have successfully logged the data from my request.

[image]

Done!

Comment: I was stuck with the same issue. Thank you for your detailed response with screenshots.

Answer (score 0):

For me, I had to add `"https://sheets.googleapis.com/*"` to `"permissions"` in the manifest.